# indexOf('a') and lastIndexOf('') in javascript returning same value for a word. "William"

Tags: javascript, web, ecmascript-6

indexOf('a') and lastIndexOd('a') for the string 'william' returns 5 for both while for the character 'l' it works fine.

Screenshots:-

[This the input for JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whymw.png)
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ObED.png)

But for the character 'l' it works like normal.

[For the character 'l'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZSpZ.png)
[Output for character 'l'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQekj.png)

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: What other "a" did you want to be found in "William" ?

Comment: There is only single 'a' so the first, last, middle or whatever index will always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can refer in [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
Thanks.